# White framework documentation and sample for testing WPF application UI

Tags: wpf, testing, white-framework

I am planning to use White framework with NUnit to test my WPF application. The assembly zip available to download from http://white.codeplex.com zip I downloaded for assemblies has a documentation NDoc folder. This documentation seem to be auto generated from the code. And there are no comments to give any hint for how to use the APIs to get WPF controls or perform any action on them. Please point me to any samples so that I can use this framework.

I have tried searching myself I don't find anything other than a this article, which is based on older version of White framework.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/john_daddamio/archive/2008/04/04/testing-wpf-applications-with-the-white-ui-test-framework.aspx

Comment: Sadly this got downvoted, but sometime when the libraries are not that popular, there is no better way to reach out to stackoverflow community users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few places you can find info to get started with:

- Most of the white documentation seems to be in the codeplex wiki - each wiki page is linked to on the main page at:

http://white.codeplex.com/

For example:

http://white.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Get%20Started&referringTitle=Home

http://white.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Programming%20using%20white&referringTitle=Home

...and so on.

- There's also some documentation in the white github repository - to find it, use the ZIP button on the main white github page to download a copy of the repo, or just use git to clone the repo:

https://github.com/petmongrels/white

Once you unzip or clone that repo, you should see the docs/ directory, which contains a brief "getting started" document ("White-Core.doc").

Comment: Thanks Bill for the links, I had gone through most of them already. But the problem was none of them cover the API documentation. But as of now, I have been able to get going following few examples found on net.

Answer (score 3):

Rajiv,

I work for Codoid. We have just published a cheat sheet for White framework. Hope it is helpful for everyone who is looking White framework examples.

http://www.codoid.com/white-framework-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Hi Akram, this was really an old question. I am not working on it currently. However your cheatsheet looks very handy and concise. I am sure it'll help people opting to use this framework!